# Perl Passing Variable to subroutines

Tags: perl, scripting, subroutine

I am trying to make changes to an existing Perl script. I am trying to add a subroutine that is called many times at different places and prints different output based on where is it called.

Basically, it creates a file and writes some business message for the business team (I am part of and hence my first time coding in Perl).

What I want/am trying for is

```
Sub filemessage ($arg1) {
  open(fh, '>', $message_file);
  print fh "$arg1/n";
  close fh;
}
```

Now I want to call this subroutine at many places (inside other subroutines) like this (there is already a fail condition based on which it is called):

```
filemessage ("failed due to reason1")
filemessage ("failed due to reason2")
```

Answer (score 7):

> ```
> Sub filemessage ($arg1) {
>   open(fh, '>', $message_file);
>   print fh "$arg1/n";
>   close fh;
> }
> ```

You were very close.

In Perl, subroutines are created with the `sub` keyword (note the lowercase 's').

The newline escape sequence is `\n`, not `/n`.

These days, we like to use lexical variables as filehandles (this, among other advantages, will automatically close the file as the variable goes out of scope).

Using `>` as the file mode will create a new, empty file each time you open the file. So it will only ever contain the last message added. Switching to `>>` will append the messages.

You should check the return value from your call to `open()` and take appropriate action if it fails (usually killing the program is the best option).

You should declare and define `$message_file` somewhere. As it's a bad idea for a subroutine to access external variables, you probably want to do that inside the subroutine.

But your biggest problem is the line:

```
sub filemessage ($arg1)
```

Traditionally Perl's subroutine parameters are passed in an array called `@_` and you need to extract them yourself.

```
my ($arg1) = @_;
```

But since Perl 5.20, there is an experimental `signatures` feature that works how you expect it to.

Putting all that together, we end up with this:

```
# turn on signatures (put this with the other "use"
# statements at the top of your file).
use experimental 'signatures';

sub filemessage ($arg1) {
  my $message_file = 'log.txt';

  open(my $fh, '>>', $message_file)
    or die "Can't open [$message_file]: $!\n";

  print $fh "$arg1\n";
}
```

Comment: I thought you said he should use append `>>`. Also, newline in the `die` message will prevent the error from printing the line number that death occurred, which is very rarely a good idea. I would not recommend a newbie to use experimental features when normal features are so simple to use.

Comment: @TLP: The `>` was a typo that I've now fixed. I know what the newline does and I added it on purpose. In a production situation, I'd probably use `croak` instead of `die` as for an often-used subroutine like this, the place where the subroutine is called from is often more useful than the line in the subroutine. I think this is an experimental feature that makes Perl work more how non-Perl programmers expect it to work, so I think it's well worth recommending (plus, I believe it's likely to come out of experimental status soon).

Answer (score 3):

Please investigate the following code piece.

Original code required just a little touch of 'love'.

- you should use `>>` instead `>` as the last one will overwrite each `sub` call
- it is useful to add timestamp into the message for debug purpose
- indicate successful program completion with exit code `0` and an error with some specific error code

**NOTE:** always include `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in your code, it will help you to avoid many pitfalls in a code. Perl will warn you when you do something what can lead to an error or potentially unexpected result.

**NOTE:** by adding `$filename` as an argument to the subroutine reusability of code piece increases, use same subroutine code to write messages in various files (sometimes very useful for debug purpose)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $filename = 'my_prog.log';
my $msg;

$msg = 'INFO: my_prog is started';
logger($filename,$msg);
$msg = 'INFO: my_prog is running';
logger($filename,$msg);
$msg = 'ERROR: my_prog immitage some error';
logger($filename,$msg);
$msg = 'INFO: my_prog is done';
logger($filename,$msg);

exit 0;

sub logger {
        my $file = shift;
        my $msg  = shift;

        open my $fh, '>>', $file
                or die "Couldn't open $file";
        say $fh join(' ', scalar localtime, $msg);
        close $fh;
}
```

Produces output

```
Mon May 24 01:23:19 2021 INFO: my_prog is started
Mon May 24 01:23:19 2021 INFO: my_prog is running
Mon May 24 01:23:19 2021 ERROR: my_prog immitage some error
Mon May 24 01:23:19 2021 INFO: my_prog is done
```

Reference: [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open), [say](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say)

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few changes that should make it work:

```
my $message_file = 'some_file';

sub filemessage {                  # sub is spelled with a lowercase 's'
    my ($arg1) = @_;               # args are passed through the array @_
    open(my $fh, '>', $message_file) or die "Error: $!"; # declare my $fh
    print $fh "$arg1\n";           # \ not /
    close $fh;
}
```

Note: The mode `>` will truncate the file so you'll only ever have at most *one* message in the file. If you want to append to the file, use the mode `>>`.

Comment: Oh, you want `>>`. You might also want to admonish all those opens+closes, using a flush instead.

Comment: @ikegami "_>>_" - I'm not sure if OP wants one message in the file or append. I'll leave that up to OP but added a note.

Comment: Args are passed to `$j`? Shouldn't that be `$_[j]`?

Comment: Args are *not* passed as `$1`, `$2`, etc.

Comment: @TedLyngmo no. `@_` yes. `$1` etc. are an entirely different thing relating to regex matching.

Comment: The code is not doing what it claims; `$_[0]` should be there instead of `$1`. (or `shift`)

Comment: Oh, sorry all, I got it mixed up. Fixed.