# perl IF executing both conditions

Tags: perl, if-statement, subroutine

I am trying to modify a perl script. The logic of what I am trying to achieve is I have created a text file with some status in it. I want to read the file and decide which subroutine will run based on it. I have manually created file with status. The if else command is not working.
Next I want to change the status in same text file depending on what subroutine was executed.

Unfortunately, as of now nothing works.

Here is the script (not the original as for security reasons)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $filename1="/usr/local/tmp/status.txt";



open Input, $filename1;
undef $/;
$StepInfo= <Input>;
close Input;
$/ = "\n";
print "value $StepInfo";

#Step 1 -
if ($StepInfo =  "Fresh" ){
        step1();
#       exit();
}

if ($StepInfo =  "stp_fail"){
        step2();
#       exit();
}


sub stepcheck {
        my ($argument1) = @_;
        my $filename1= shift;
        open(FH, '>', $filename1);
        print FH "$argument1\n";
        close FH;
}

sub step1 {
        my $StepInfo= shift;
        print "Step1 completed\n";
        print $StepInfo;
        stepcheck ('dh_fail');
}

sub step2 {
        my $StepInfo= shift;
        print "Step2 completed\n";
        print $StepInfo;
        stepcheck ('Test');
}

#open($FH, '>', $filename1);
#print $FH "Fresh\n";
#close ($FH);

#perl -i -pe 'y|\r||d' script.pl
```

I set status to "stp_fail". when i execute the script I am expecting step2 to be executed. I see the its reading the right status but not executing the correct step rather both of them

```
-bash-4.2$ ./test_script.pl

value stp_fail

Step1 completed

Step2 completed
```

Additionally the script is not changing the status in the text file. Instead, it creates 2 new files named `Test` and `dh_fail`.

Comment: `=` is not comparison. `==` is numeric comparison and `eq` is for strings. Start your script file with both `use strict;` and `use warnings;` so that perl can warn you about such things.

Comment: I rolled back your changes; please don't make changes which invalidate existing answers. I notice that you have asked a new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67773266/perl-if-not-executing anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I found below things in your code. Please have a look into these points.

1. In `if` condition, you were checking the content with `=`, which is wrong.

Since you need to validate the string in which matches with either `Fresh` or `stp_fail` use condition like below. If these are the exact matches.

```
if ($StepInfo eq "Fresh" ){ #same as ($StepInfo =~ /^Fresh$/)
    step1();
}

if ($StepInfo eq "stp_fail"){ #same as ($StepInfo =~ /^stp_fail$/)
    step2();
}
```

If you just want to match if the content something like `Fresh` or `stp_fail` exists, then below expression would be fine.

```
if ($StepInfo =~ /Fresh/ ){
    step1();
}

if ($StepInfo =~ /stp_fail/){
    step2();
}
```

2. Always append content into a log file instead of rewriting content into a file. For your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67666794/perl-passing-variable-to-subroutines) Dave and Ted mentioned in their answers.
   And always use lexical variables as filehandles (As Dave mentioned).
3. Since you're passing single argument to the `stepcheck()` subroutine, `$argument1` and `$filename1` in function definition. I believe you must have to pass two arguments as per my understanding with variables which you have declared (As of now, I have kept single argument in the below script).
4. Most important thing is include `use strict; use warnings;`. Which would help you to find most of the errors/warnings in your script.

Modified script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my $filename1 = "status.txt";
my $StepInfo;

open(my $input_fh, $filename1)
    or die "Can't open [$filename1]: $!\n";
undef $/;
$StepInfo = <$input_fh>;
close $input_fh;

$/ = "\n";
print "Value $StepInfo\n";

if ($StepInfo eq "Fresh" ){
    print "Matches with Fresh, Entering into step1()\n";
    step1();
}

if ($StepInfo eq "stp_fail"){
    print "Mathes with stp_fail, Entering into step2()\n";
    step2();
}

sub stepcheck {
    my $filename1 = shift;
    my $argument1 = $filename1; #If you need different value in $argument1, you can pass it in stepcheck definition and grab it here with ($filename1, $$argument1) = @_;
    my $FH;
    open ($FH, '>', $filename1)
        or die "Can't open [$FH]: $!\n";
    print $FH "$argument1\n";
    close $FH;
}

sub step1 {
    print "Step1 completed\n";
    stepcheck('dh_fail');
}

sub step2 {
    print "Step2 completed\n";
    stepcheck('Test');
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add arguments to the calls to `step1` and `step2` in your modified script. Also, `stepcheck` is still wrong, as `$argument1` and `$filename1` will always be equal, which is probably not the intended behavior.

Comment: @Dada Corrected.